# How are parentheses interpreted at the command line?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

While reading up on how to set up `grub`, I came across an article claiming that I need to use one of the following two syntaxes,

```
echo \(hd0,0\) >> /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

or

```
echo '(hd0,0)' >> /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

because, at the command line, parentheses are interpreted in a special way. What is special about the parentheses? How are they interpreted?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Parentheses denote a subshell in bash.  To quote the `man bash` page:

```
(list)    list  is  executed  in  a  subshell  environment (see COMMAND
          EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below).  Variable assignments and builtin 
          commands that affect the shell's environment do not remain in 
          effect after the command completes.  The return status is the
          exit status of list.
```

where a `list` is just a normal sequence of commands.

This is actually quite portable and not specific to just `bash` though.  The [POSIX Shell Command Language spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) has the following description for the `(compound-list)` syntax:

> Execute *compound-list* in a subshell environment; see [Shell Execution Environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12). Variable assignments and built-in commands that affect the environment shall not remain in effect after the list finishes.

Comment: In bash and other shells...?

Comment: bash is the one i was asking about...

Comment: What's the difference between `$()` and `()`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai The `$()` is command substitution, the `()` is a subshell. Both of them run commands, the difference is what happens to the output. The names are much easier to search than the symbols. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213530/9537

Answer (score 22):

A command list embedded between **parentheses** runs as a subshell.

Variables in a subshell are not visible outside the block of code in the subshell. They are not accessible to the parent process, to the shell that launched the subshell. These are, in effect, local variables.

See [Linuxtopia - Chapter 20. Subshells](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/subshells.html)