# Difference of using () and $() to execute a series of commands

Tags: shell, shell-script, pipe, command-substitution

I am currently trying to make a script that creates bytes that will be piped as input to netcat.

Here is the idea of the script:

```
(perl -e "print \"$BYTES\x00\";

cat file;

perl -e "print \"More bytes\"x16 . \"\r\n\"";) | netcat ip port
```

I tried using both using a subshell and command substitution (ex. with $()) to execute the commands. However I fail to understand why the output of the script when using command substitution is wrong. I suspect that command substitution incorrectly pipes its output when executing multiple commands. Can someone explain to me why this is so?

**EDIT**

Here is the variant that used command substitution:

```
$(perl -e "print \"$BYTES\x00\";

cat file;

perl -e "print \"More bytes\"x16 . \"\r\n\"";) | netcat ip port
```

Comment: Command substitution is replaced by it's output. That is, the output of that command in substitution form will not be piped into ``netcat`` because it will just be bare text. If you, for example, added ``echo`` before the command substitution starts, you may find that it works.

Comment: @HalosGhost So you mean to say that the hex bytes I tried to generate became text in ascii form? I tried to do a hexdump of the outputs and what confuses me is the output from the command substitution contains an HTML document and the hex bytes i generated seems to be inside it.

Comment: No, I mean, that you can think of any command inside a command substitution as being equivalent to typing the output of that command. Which means, in your second example, the result is just bare text. So, nothing is piped into ``netcat`` because nothing is run.

Comment: @HalosGhost I see.  So the output of command substitution is same as typing in stdin causing nothing to be piped am I correct? I am new to scripting and did not understand this. Thank you so much. If you transfer your comment to the answers section I'll accept it.

Comment: I tried to expand on my answer as much as possible to make the picture as clear and simple to understand as I could.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \` (backquote/backtick) mean in commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands)

Comment: Also related: [difference between ${} and $() in shell script](https://superuser.com/q/935374/354511) (on [SU]) and [What's the difference between $(stuff) and \`stuff\`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/80216)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay, let's break this down. A subshell executes its contents in a chain (i.e., it groups them). This actually makes intuitive sense as a subshell is created simply by surrounding the chain of commands with `()`. But, aside from the contents of the subshell being grouped together in execution, you can still use a subshell as if it were a single command. That is, a subshell still has an `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` so you can pipe things to and from a subshell.

On the other hand, command substitution is not the same thing as simply chaining commands together. Rather, command substitution is meant to act a bit like a variable access but with a function call. Variables, unlike commands, do not have the standard file descriptors so you cannot pipe anything to or from a variable (generally speaking), and the same is true of command substitutions.

To try to make this more clear, what follows are a set of maybe-unclear (but accurate) examples and a set of, what I think may be, more easily-understood examples.

Let's say the `date -u` command gives the following:

```
Thu Jul  2 13:42:27 UTC 2015
```

But, we want to manipulate the output of this command. So, let's pipe it into something like `sed`:

```
user@host~> date -u | sed -e 's/ /    /g'
Thu    Jul        2    13:42:27    UTC    2015
```

Wow, that was fun! The following is completely equivalent to above (barring some environment differences that you can read about in the man pages about your shell):

```
user@host~> (date -u) | sed -e 's/ /    /g'
Thu    Jul        2    13:42:27    UTC    2015
```

That should be no surprise since all we did was group `date -u`. However, if we do the following, we are going to get something that may seem a bit odd at first:

```
user@host~> $(date -u) | sed -e 's/ /    /g'
command not found: Thu
```

This is because `$(date -u)` is equivalent to typing out exactly what `date -u` outputs. So the above is equivalent to the following:

```
user@host~> Thu Jul  2 13:42:27 UTC 2015 | sed -e 's/ /    /g'
```

Which will, of course, error out because `Thu` is not a command (at least not one I know of); and it certainly doesn't pipe anything to `stdout` (so `sed` will never get any input).

But, since we know that command substitutions act like variables, we can easily fix this problem because we know how to pipe the value of a variable into another command:

```
user@host~> echo $(date -u) | sed -e 's/ /    /g'
Thu    Jul        2    13:42:27    UTC    2015
```

But, [as with any variable in bash](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html), you should probably quote command substitutions with `""`.

Now, for the perhaps-simpler example; consider the following:

```
user@host~> pwd
/home/hypothetical
user@host~> echo pwd
pwd
user@host~> echo "$(pwd)"
/home/hypothetical
user@host~> echo "$HOME"
/home/hypothetical
user@host~> echo (pwd)
error: your shell will tell you something weird that roughly means “Whoa! you tried to have me echo something that isn't text!”
user@host~> (pwd)
/home/hypothetical
```

I am not sure how to describe it any simpler than that. The command substitution works just like a variable access where the subshell still operates like a command.

Answer (score 11):

## Subshell

`(command)` will execute `command` in a subshell. This is useful, if you have more than one command.

- `(ls) | wc` will pipe the output of `ls` to `wc`, obviously you can write `ls | wc`.
- `(ls ; date) | wc` will pipe the output of both `ls` and `date` to `wc`. Using `ls ; date | wc` will result in only `date` being piped to `wc`.

## Substitution

`$(command)` will execute `command` and replace by the output. E.g.

```bsh
echo $(date)
```

will replace `$(date)` by `Thu Jul  2 15:20:43 CEST 2015`, which results in

```bsh
echo Thu Jul  2 15:20:43 CEST 2015
```

## Putting both together

You can combine the two.

```bsh
file=/hello/word
( printf "%s has %d bytes\n" "${file}" $(wc -c < "$file") ; date ) | netcat ...
```

Here, you can use `"$file"` or `"${file}"`.

Do not forget to quote filename, in fantasy world filename are plain file, whereas in real world filename usually contains new line, space, comma, tabulation and parenthesis.

Comment: Does that mean that i cannot use command substitution on multiple commands such as using ; to separate them?

Comment: Sure you can. It's just not going to pipe anything to ``stdout`` and will instead replace itself with the result of the expression.

Comment: As [Kusalananda says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440088/80216#comment815043_440088), “Displaying the output of a command using command substitution and `echo` is a bad example of command substitution because 1) the output would have been displayed anyway, 2) `printf` is safer to use for variable data.” I wonder how much the `echo $(date)` example helps anybody learn to understand command substitution. I am biased toward [my own example](https://superuser.com/q/935374/354511#935427), `ls -ld $(date +%B).txt` (which shows long information about the `July.txt` file).

Comment: P.S. As I’m sure you know, you should use `"$file"` (i.e., use quotes), not because your example needs it, but because we want to teach good habits and lead by example.