# Shell script not executing a command returned from a function

Tags: shell-script, date

Can someone please explain why this doesn't work? I have a bash function that simply returns the number of seconds in a duration timestamp.

**Shell script function**

```
seconds() { 
    result=$(echo "\"1970-01-01 $1+0\"")
    echo date +%s -d $result
}
```

**Calling the function**

```
seconds 00:00:02.00 #works
```

Produces the following output `date +%s -d "1970-01-01 00:00:02.00+0"` if I copy this exact text and execute it in the terminal it works.

```
$(seconds 00:00:02.00) #error
```

However this returns an error:

```
date: extra operand ‘00:00:02.00+0"’
```

What's the problem here? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [don't need to use `echo`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2116) at any point here.

Using the subshell, you're executing the output of the `seconds` function which is [generally ill-advised](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2091) as it can cause unexpected behavior like you're seeing.

Instead, simplify your function to run the `date` command itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
seconds () {
    date -d "1970-01-01 $1+0" "+%s"
}

seconds 00:00:02.00
```

Output: `2`

Comment: Small note that what the OP is using is command substitution vice subshell.  A thorough explanation of what John is saying can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213544/151609