# Are subshells run in parallel by default?

Tags: bash, shell-script, parallelism, subshell

This question follows from [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26063/how-are-parentheses-interpreted-at-the-command-line) and one of its answers' recommendation to read [Linuxtopia - Chapter 20. Subshells](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/subshells.html).

I'm a bit confused by this statement at the Linuxtopia site:

> subshells let the script do parallel processing, in effect executing multiple subtasks simultaneously.
>   <sub>https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/subshells.html</sub>

Does this mean that subshells, run from a script, are always run in parallel to the original script? Experimentally, this does not appear to be the case, but I'd be grateful for expert confirmation one way or the other.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

# This script reliably prints:
# hello
# world
# 0
# ...implying that the the subshell is not run in parallel with this script.

(echo hello;
echo world)

echo $?
```

.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

# This script prints:
# 0
# hello
# world
# ...implying that the the subshell is run in parallel with this script.

(echo hello;
echo world) &

echo $?
```

Is the use of `&` what the Linuxtopia site might have meant by "*[letting] the script do parallel processing*"?

---

Note: I'm familiar with the concept of suffixing commands with `&` in bash...it runs said command as a background process. So my question is more about whether command(s) executed in a subshell are run as background/parallel process *by default*, or if addition of the `&` here, as well, is what causes the background/parallel execution. The wording of the Linuxtopia article, to me, implied the former, which doesn't appear to match observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how you create the subshell.

`( command )` will run `command` in a subshell and wait for the subshell to complete before continuing.

`command &` will run `command` in a subshell in the background.  The shell will continue on to the next command without waiting for the subshell to finish.  This may be used for parallel processing.

`coproc command` is similar to `command &`, but also establishes a two-way pipe between the main shell and the subshell.