# When are grouped parentheses for multiple options necessary?

Tags: bash, find, options

I am using the `find` and `grep` commands.

Getting quite confused about when multiple options are joined by "or"
with the `-o` flag and the use of grouped parentheses, and when grouped parentheses are not used.

When using `find`, grouped parentheses seem necessary

```
find $fdir ( -name *.texi -o -name *.org )
```

When using `grep`, grouped parentheses not used

```
grep --include "*.texi" --exclude "*.org"
```

Comment: When the default order of operations is not what you want.

Comment: That `find` command should give you an error about `syntax error near unexpected token \`('`, does it not? You need to escape parentheses from the shell in order for `find` to see them, so that command should have been written as `find "$fdir" \( -name '*.texi' -o -name '*.org' \)` for the parentheses to work for `find`.

Comment: @terdon You are correct, requires `\(`.

Comment: Related: [\`find\` with multiple \`-name\` and \`-exec\` executes only the last matches of \`-name\`](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/102191)

Answer (score 14):

Most programs, including `grep` don't treat parenthesis as arguments specially. If you did this:

```
grep "(" --include "*.texi" --exclude "*.org" ")"
```

`grep` would treat the first `(` as the pattern to search for, and the last `)` as a filename.<sup>(*)</sup> Same as if they were `foo` and `bar` instead. So, you can't group options to `grep`.

---

But here's the thing: `-name`, `-type`, `-o`, and `(` etc. aren't *options* to `find`. It does take some options, namely `-P`/`-H`/`-L`, which affect symlink processing, but these aren't options. Instead, they're part of the search expression, which is a thing specific to `find`. <sup>(**)</sup>

Emphasis on *expression* there. When you give `find` the expression `( -name *.texi -o -name *.org )` it's more like the C-like expression

```
( patternmatch(filename, "*.texi") || patternmatch(filename, "*.texi") )
```

than anything else. And `find` evaluates that expression for each file it sees. If you had e.g. this instead:

```
( -name *.texi -o -name *.org ) -printf something
```

You'd need the parens, because without them:

```
-name *.texi -o -name *.org -printf something
```

would be the same as

```
-name *.texi -o -name *.org -a -printf something
```

because there's an implied *and* between atoms unless `-o` is given, and then the expression would be

```
patternmatch(...) || patternmatch(...) && printf(...)
```

and the *and* operation binds tighter than the *or* operation, exactly in the same way it does in pretty much all programming languages, and in the same way multiplication binds tighter than addition. And `find` can't know what you wanted, because it supports arbitrary expressions.<sup>(***)</sup> So, in this case, it wouldn't work like you want without the parens.

---

As others noted, the command you have doesn't need parens, since if there are no "actions" (`-print`, `-exec` etc.) in the find expression, it defaults to printing matching filenames, and also implicitly puts parenthesis around the expression.

So,

```
find "$fdir" -name "*.texi" -o -name "*.org"
```

acts like

```
find "$fdir" \( -name "*.texi" -o -name "*.org" \) -print
```

but if you explicitly put the `-print` there, you also need to explicitly put the parenthesis to get the processing order right. See: [`find` with multiple `-name` and `-exec` executes only the last matches of `-name`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102191/170373)

---

Going back to `grep`: `grep` doesn't take parens, and doesn't need them, since it doesn't process expressions. It has no concept of nesting or operators like *and* and *or* in general. Instead, it has hard-coded behaviours. With `--include` and `--exclude`, I think it tries to fulfil both the include and exclude rules at the same time. (Or, at least one of the individual `--include` rules and none of the individual `--exclude` rules.) But with multiple search patterns, it's enough to match one, *or* another. Both of these are static rules: you can't give it a more complicated expression of which patterns should match.

---

<sub>(* GNU grep would take the middle ones as options, other implementations might take them as filenames too, as the non-option argument earlier stopped option processing. Also, you need to quote or escape the parens to prevent their special meaning to the *shell*; that's unrelated to what `grep` does with them.)</sub>

<sub>(** In the same way that it's specific to `grep` that the first non-option argument is a pattern, and only the rest are filenames, or that the last argument to `mv` is a destination while the others are files to move, and it's specific to `git` what it does with whatever arguments it takes. The tools do different things, so they have to use the command line arguments in different ways.)</sub>

<sub>(*** Someone once said that evaluating expressions is the *main thing* `find` does. That is to say, it doesn't find filenames to print them, it goes through a tree of files to *evaluate an expression* on them. Printing and running external commands is just a side-effect.)</sub>

Comment: Then I have to change my plan when using grep because I end up with enclosing parentheses when using `"${isufx[@]}"`. I got `grep -hir "${esufx[@]}" "${isufx[@]}" "${ictx[@]}" "$@"`.  Got to simplify my code with a different school of thought.

Comment: @Pietru, the parens on grep also wouldn't mean anything, since it doesn't handle arbitrary expressions. It just collects all the include and exclude rules together, and does what it does. Which I think boils down to something like _(match on any include) and not (match on any exclude)_

Comment: @Pietru some of the confusion might be naming-related — `{}` aren’t parentheses, they’re curly braces (or brackets).

Comment: @Pietru, I'm not sure if this is what you were thinking, but since Stephen mentioned it, let's clarify that the braces that are part of the array syntax, in `"${array[@]}"` are in no way related to what goes to the command (e.g. find's `{}` for `-exec`), and neither do the parenthesis in a command substitution (`$(...)`) have anything to do with the parens in a `find` expression. You can use `opts=-qv; grep "${opts}" hello filename`, or `opts=(-q -v); grep "${opts[@]}" hello filename`, even if `grep` itself doesn't process parens or braces.

Answer (score 7):

There’s no general rule: what a given command recognises as arguments depends on the command. [`grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) doesn’t use parentheses for grouping arguments.

For [`find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), parentheses are only needed when the precedence of *and* versus *or* needs to be overridden; this is similar to the use of parentheses in mathematics. In your example, they are not needed, because the default precedence gives the expression the same overall meaning:

```
find "$fdir" -name '*.texi' -o -name '*.org'
```

Comment: Seems to be necessary with `find $fdir -name *.texi -o -name *.org "$@"`

Comment: @Pietru never use patterns unquoted like that. If you have any files matching the patterns in the current directory, then the patterns will be expanded to the matching files by the shell before launching find, so `find` will never see the pattern but only its expansion in the top level directory. Always quote: `find "$fdir" -name "*.texi" -o -name "*.org" "$@"`.

Comment: @Pietru yes, if you add arguments with `"$@"` you need to ensure that the resulting overall expression still reflects your intent; `find` can’t guess that for you — it doesn’t even know that the first part is hard-coded and the second isn’t.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for the confusion is that there is no standard on how command-line parameters are interpreted by programs. In general, interpretation of parameters is left to the programmer, though the [GNU coding standard](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces) recommends that programs use the `getopt()` and `getopt_long()` functions (from the [GNU C library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html)) for that purpose.

That means that the interpretation of the parentheses to define operator precedence is a function of `find`, and not of the shell used to invoke `find`. The programmers of `grep` "simply" didn't implement their options-parsing algorithm that way, so `grep` wouldn't understand this notation in the first place.

**Note, however** that parentheses have a special meaning in the shell: They denote that the enclosed content is a command to be run [in a sub-shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26063/377345). So, the command as you posted it should actually not work; as mentioned by @terdon, you have to escape the parentheses (like `\( ... \)`) in order to have the shell pass them to `find` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think the manual has some insights on how `find` uses the parenthesis that can help you:

[2.12 Combining Primaries With Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Combining-Primaries-With-Operators)

> Operators build a complex expression from tests and actions. The
> operators are, in order of decreasing precedence:
>
> ```
> ( expr )
> ```
>
> Force precedence. True if `expr` is true.
>
> ```
> ! expr
> -not expr
> ```
>
> True if `expr` is false. In some shells, it is necessary to protect the ‘!’ from shell interpretation by quoting it.
>
> ```
> expr1 expr2 expr1 -a
> expr2 expr1 -and expr2
> ```
>
> And; `expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is false.
>
> ```
> expr1 -o expr2 expr1 -or expr2
> ```
>
> Or; `expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is true.
>
> ```
> expr1 , expr2
> ```
>
> List; both `expr1` and `expr2` are always evaluated. True if `expr2` is true. The value of `expr1` is discarded. This operator lets you do
> multiple independent operations on one traversal, without depending on
> whether other operations succeeded. The two operations `expr1` and `expr2`
> are not always fully independent, since `expr1` might have side effects
> like touching or deleting files, or it might use `-prune’ which would also affect` expr2`.
>
> `find` searches the directory tree rooted at each file name by
> evaluating the expression from left to right, according to the rules
> of precedence, until the outcome is known (the left hand side is false
> for `-and`, true for `-or`), at which point find moves on to the next
> file name.

Comment: Note that the question doesn't only ask about `find`, but also `grep`, and why parentheses are used with `find` sometimes, but not with e.g. `grep`.

Comment: Indeed, as the other answers address the question fully, I thought that adding some information on how `find` uses the parenthesis would be helpful. I was doubting if it should be a comment. I trust your opinion on this matter.